# vim in screen: vim does not highlight syntax when I'm in a screen session

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I cannot see any syntax highlighting in any language (e.g. python, c++ and sh) when I use vim within a screen session. The line numbers are in color though. 
I precise that my terminal (in screen too) is able to show 256 colors schemes (I tested with the 256colors perl script found here: http://frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/ ).

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is the output of `$ echo $TERM` in your terminal and in screen? What is the output of `:echo $TERM` in vim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM Colorschemes in Screen & PuTTy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630013/vim-colorschemes-in-screen-putty)

Comment: no, it's not a duplicate: 1st: I tried the solutions given in that thread, 2nd: I don't use putty.

Comment: I have indeed 2 different answers with `echo $TERM`: in the terminal it's `xterm-256color` and in screen it's `screen-bce`.

Comment: OK, just make sure it's `screen-256color` in screen.

Comment: Well, I changed that in my .screenrc file, `echo $TERM` gives the "good" output, but still no syntax highlighting in vi. I tried to follow directions here too https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=67464 but that did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is the issue/solution:
I used to call vim by using `$vi`, indeed:

```
$ which vi
alias vi='vim'
    /usr/bin/vim
```

But:

```
$ screen
$ which vi
/bin/vi
```

I just learnt that screen doesn't load this system level alias which is tricky.

Comment: For future users, could the OP or someone please post the solution? This is the same problem I'm having, but now I need to go out to the webosphere to find out how to fix it ;)

Comment: I added the alias to my .bashrc, but maybe there is a more appropriate screen-specific solution.

Comment: this has nothing to do with why vi syntax highlighting isn't working.  even if they were running diff versions of vim, :syntax enable would still work.  The problem is that vim doesn't consider the current $TERM to be color compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  In my case, I was running a version of screen from brew.  brew doesn't use ~/.screenrc as its startup file.  So there's two solutions to this.

1) Set your term in the screenrc that brew_screen is expecting.  This might be /opt/etc/screenrc.  I didn't try this method, so I'm not sure.

2) Make an alias for screen that sets the term to what you want it to be.  In this case, screen-256color is sufficient.  I added the following line to my bash_profile, which is symlinked to my bashrc (mac problems):

```
alias screen='screen -T screen-256color'
```